# Failed to OpenActiveSession with "an unknown error occurred" at iOS Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin.ios, xamarin, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm trying to integrate facebook into iPhone app using Xamarin MonoTouch.
I'm using this SDK component:
http://components.xamarin.com/view/facebookios

```
var activeSessionOpened = FBSession.OpenActiveSession(false);
Debug.WriteLine("Active Session Opened: {0}", activeSessionOpened);

activeSessionOpened = FBSession.OpenActiveSession(new string[] { }, true,
    (session, status, error) =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Active Session State Changed. Status: {0}. Error: {1}", status, error.DebugDescription);
    });
```

Every time during 2nd request to OpenActiveSession I'm getting the following error:

> "Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=2 \"The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 2.)\" UserInfo=0x1e081e60
>   {com.facebook.sdk:ErrorLoginFailedReason=com.facebook.sdk:SystemLoginCancelled,
>   com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey=Error Domain=com.apple.accounts
>   Code=7 \"**The Facebook server could not fulfill this access request: An
>   unknown error occurred\"** UserInfo=0x1cdba190
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=The Facebook server could not fulfill this
>   access request: An unknown error occurred},
>   com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=,
>   expirationDate: (null), refreshDate: (null), attemptedRefreshDate:
>   0001-12-30 00:00:00 +0000, permissions:(null)>}"

Sample here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/19503836/iPhoneFace2.zip

I appreciate any suggestion and help.
Thanks!